# How To Update WordPress Custom Plugin For Customer?

Tags: plugin-development

I am building a custom wordPress plugin for customers. It is a support plugin. It will be install in more than 100 customers. Customers will install the plugin. How can I update the plugin from one place, and update to all customers? What is the procedure for this? I do not want to ask them to download it and install it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

please Check links:
https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker

This is a custom update checker library for WordPress plugins and themes. It lets you add automatic update notifications and one-click upgrades to your WP Plugin.

and another ref.
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html